# Cumulative Distribution Function Help

Tags: probability, statistics, functions

[image]If you have a question asking for the lower quartile of a cumulative distribution function, and this function has two different lines, how would you determine is the lower quartile lies in the first section or the second? Just that it would save time for me knowing which one to do the workings for.

Comment: "this function has two different lines" What is a "line" of a function?

Comment: Ill add an example.

Comment: Is this a discrete distribution?

Comment: Yes it is, just that if it says find I dont know, the 40th percentile, how would you know if it lies in the first or second area.

Comment: BTW, cummulative distribution function is a monotone increasing function; the graph in the picture is probability density function (it certainly integrates to $1$).

Comment: This is not a cumulative distribution function but a *probability* distribution function and the distribution is not discrete but *continuous*. At this level, I see few more productive steps for you than to read carefully a source on the subject, say https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function.

Comment: That wasnt the question by the way, the function at hand was F(r), that was merely me trying to show by what I meant different lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution. You compute the quantile function (i.e. the inverse cumulative distribution) $F^{-1}(y)$ for $0\le y \le 1$ using three different cases$$
\begin{equation*}
 F^{-1}(y) =
\begin{cases}
a + \sqrt{(b-a)(c-a)y}     & y < t\\
c                          & y = t\\
b - \sqrt{(b-a)(b-c)(1-y)} & y > t\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
$$
with $t = \frac{c-a}{b-a} \cdot$